# Собственный сервис предоставления Callback виджетов

Tags: callback, asterisk, sip

Требуется организовать сервис предоставления callback виджетов.

Вопросы таковы:

1. Что выбрать Asterisk или FreeSwitch(А может и что-то другое)?
2. Где организовать сервер для тестирования(Виртуалка или отдельный пк)?
3. Что потребуется для организации callback?
4. Какую SIP телефонию посоветуете?
5. С чего начать? Посоветуйте что почитать можно

Заранее спасибо c: